# How to only display the total count of a number of lines without the count being displayed every line?

Tags: python, text, jupyter-notebook, counter

I have been assigned to find certain lines that contain the word "From:" in a .txt document. I have found all of these, but I am having trouble displaying the total number of lines that contain the word "From:". I have a counter variable in place, but each time I execute the code, the counter is displayed after each line (ex. 1, 2, 3, instead of just 27 at the end of all the output. See picture for reference). Can someone help me fix this?

```
email_file=open('mbox-short.txt','r')
counter=0
for line in email_file:
    if line.startswith("From:")==True:
        print(line.upper(),end="")
        counter+=1
        print(counter)
email_file.close()
```

[Reference picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRmzC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the position of the line of code print(counter) to the end so it does not print everytime it loops.

```
email_file=open('mbox-short.txt','r')
counter=0
for line in email_file:
    if line.startswith("From:")==True:
        print(line.upper(),end="")
        counter+=1
email_file.close()
print(counter)
```

Comment: @EthanSmith If my answer was helpful to you, may I ask you to validate my answer as correct one?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `print(counter)` statement here is *inside* the body of the loop, so it prints on each iteration (see the indentation). This should fix the issue:

```
email_file=open('mbox-short.txt','r')
counter=0
for line in email_file:
    if line.startswith("From:")==True:
        print(line.upper(),end="")
        counter+=1
print(counter)
email_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `print` function call is aligned inside of the `for` loop, which causes that print-counter-after-each-line problem.

As for coding style, you could just remove that `==True` thing because you've already got a boolean value for testing. And I would also suggest the more convenient `with` context manager for processing files.

In short (if you don't need to print every line starting with "From:"):

```
with open('mbox-short.txt', 'r') as f:
    count = sum([line.startswith("From:") for line in f])
    print(count)
```